# Multiple Jquery modal Dialog Boxes in one page?

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I am brand stinking new to jquery and attempting to have a "Services" page for a tech website I am working on.  I am having trouble with different services opening the same info in the window.

Basically I am using the code straight from the demo.  Any ideas on how to have multiple windows in the same page?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to see exactly what you are talking about. Except that multiple and modal is an oxymoron. Could you give a hint on what kind of dialog boxes you're talking about ? Some plugin you are using ?

Comment: @subtenante - my best guess is that it's jQuery UI Dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many modal dialog boxes have the ability to insert data into the modal dialog by use of an iFrame. I'm not sure which plugin you are using (or the built-in jQuery ones I guess) but I'm fairly certain that it allows you to have one modal dialog whose content changes based on what was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution for the Multiple Modal ,[jQmodal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/#examples)