# Trying to have multiple jquery dialog boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know there is a similar question to this one [Multiple Jquery modal Dialog Boxes in one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972316/multiple-jquery-modal-dialog-boxes-in-one-page)
but it does not give me the answer I need

here is the js:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    show:"puff",
    hide:"puff"
});

$(".opener").click(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
});

$("#dialog2").dialog({
    autoOpen:false,
    modal:true,
    show:"puff",
    hide:"puff"
});

$(".opener2").click(function () {
    $("#dialog2").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

Even tho on #dialog2 it says autoOpen:false it auto opens anyway... does anyone have a solution? Here is my website [timothy.techbypaul.com](http://timothy.techbypaul.com/) when you first arrive it will popup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another initialization of your second dialog with `autoOpen: true` option.

Check it in your [main script](http://timothy.techbypaul.com/js/mainjs.js) in `jQuery(document).ready` section.